# need a regex for matching repeating lines of symbols (example: ------------- or *****************)

Tags: php, regex

I want to be able to remove linebreaks etc that people make by using recurring characters, for example:

```
****************************************************
----------------------------------------------------
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

etc

i'd like to not have to specify which characters it will match, maybe all that are NOT \w characters?

also note they will not always start/end on a new line..

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you'll have to decide on the threshold length to decide which ones are really separators, call it `N`, then you can do:

```
$input = preg_replace('/(\W)\1{N-1,}/,'',$input);
```

which deletes `N` or more consecutive `non-word` char.

Comment: $dd = preg_replace('/(\W)\1{10-1,}/i', '', $dd);  doesnt seem to work even testing on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ ?

Comment: I'm guessing that was pseudocode, and what he meant was `preg_replace('/(\W)\1{9,}/i', '', $dd);`.  The subtraction was for you to do, not the regex parser ;)